# Overleaf Enable Vim Mode

Tags: overleaf

According to [this page](https://www.overleaf.com/blog/19-upgrades-and-simplifications-vim-and-emacs-faster-previews-and-editor-streamlining) the vim editing mode can be enabled in the account settings, but I can not find it.
Even after joining the beta program there is no option to enable this feature.

How can I enable the vim editor mode in Overleaf?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.  Questions specific to Overleaf are probably better directed to their support staff through their website.  Although their support staff does seem to do an admirable job of patrolling through here to help out where they can.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

(I'm on support staff at Overleaf.) Sorry about the outdated blog post. Those instructions refer to our old v1 editor which has now been retired. I'll make a note to update the post with new instructions.

On Overleaf v2, this setting is managed in the project menu. Open a project, then click on the Overleaf menu in the upper left. Scroll down to "Keybindings" where you can select Vim or Emacs. This setting is remembered across projects.

Comment: I followed the blog: https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/How_can_I_define_custom_Vim_macros_in_a_vimrc_file_on_Overleaf%3F#Example_script_with_TamperMonkey_to_add_keybindings, but how can I activate settings such as "visual-lines"?

Comment: I was searching this as well and only found this answer after some time. Would be awesome if you could update this post :)

Comment: @Sebb my apologies, I assume this got lost in my sea of browser tabs back then and I never saved my changes to the post. Now done. Sorry about that.

Comment: @PaulGessler No problem, I found it after all ;) Thanks for updating it!

Comment: @PaulGessler: On that note, is it possible to add vim statusline in Overleaf? Adding a .vimrc does not work.

Comment: @stephanmg I'm not sure these days. If you can't find anything current on Overleaf's help pages, I'd recommend contacting Overleaf support to ask. [(I no longer work there, but I didn't edit all my old posts to avoid spamming the front page.)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10072/editing-out-someones-professional-affiliation-to-a-company#comment29590_10072)